# pd.concat() adding NaN value column to beginning of rows

Tags: python, pandas

Goal: to concatenate 2 similar DataFrames together, and sort by first column.

The problem is `new_df` has some records *"pushed*" to the right, starting I *think* with a `tab` or `\t`.

This causes an inconsistent shape of a DataFrame.

**Code:**

```py
import pandas as pd

df_1 = ...
df_2 = ...

new_df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
new_df.sort_values(new_df.columns[0], ascending=True)
```

---

**`df_1`:**

```
           1                                                  2                                                  3
0  Emissions  305-1~GHG emissions in metric tons of CO2e~Gro...  Emissions for Gross direct (Scope 1) GHG emiss...
1  Emissions  305-1~GHG emissions in metric tons of CO2e~Bio...  Emissions for Biogenic CO2 emissions was 14681...
2  Emissions    305-1~Direct (Scope 1) GHG emissions by gas~CO2  Emissions for CO2 was 107973 tons in year 2014...
3  Emissions    305-1~Direct (Scope 1) GHG emissions by gas~N20  Emissions for N20 was 91661 tons in year 2014;...
4  Emissions   305-1~Direct (Scope 1) GHG emissions by gas~HFCs  Emissions for HFCs was 31744 tons in year 2014...
```

**`df_2`:**

```
                            0                                                  1                                                  2
0                   Emissions  103-1~Explanation of the material topic and it...  consumption rate fossil fuels coal oil emissio...
1                   Emissions   103-2~The management approach and its components  how evaluate companys environmental management...
2                   Emissions        103-3~Evaluation of the management approach  evaluation effectiveness companys environmenta...
3  Customer Health and Safety  103-1~Explanation of the material topic and it...  health safety corporate policy needsthe americ...
4  Customer Health and Safety   103-2~The management approach and its components  management approach employee customer wellbein...
```

**new_df:**

```
     0          1                                                  2                                                  3
0  NaN  Emissions  305-1~GHG emissions in metric tons of CO2e~Gro...  Emissions for Gross direct (Scope 1) GHG emiss...
1  NaN  Emissions  305-1~GHG emissions in metric tons of CO2e~Bio...  Emissions for Biogenic CO2 emissions was 14681...
2  NaN  Emissions    305-1~Direct (Scope 1) GHG emissions by gas~CO2  Emissions for CO2 was 107973 tons in year 2014...
3  NaN  Emissions    305-1~Direct (Scope 1) GHG emissions by gas~N20  Emissions for N20 was 91661 tons in year 2014;...
4  NaN  Emissions   305-1~Direct (Scope 1) GHG emissions by gas~HFCs  Emissions for HFCs was 31744 tons in year 2014...
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need start `RangeIndex` from `0` like in `df2.columns`:

```
df_1.columns = range(len(df_1.columns))
```

Or:

```
df_1.columns -= 1
```

Another idea is set both columns:

```
df_1.columns = range(len(df_1.columns))
df_2.columns = range(len(df_2.columns))
```

And then join:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
```

Comment: Doing `df.columns = range(len(df.columns))` for both worked. Cheers @jezrael